# How do we know if there's someone working on my question?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, unanswered-questions

I'm just curious (and sometimes annoyed) that, it's sometimes really hard to tell whether a question is being solved by someone, or just forgotten by the community. Especially, when a problem is hard to solve, it could take weeks or months without knowing anyone that is working on it.

Someone would say, you're going to place a bounty on it. I don't really think this is a good way. Placing a bounty might be a waste of "precious" reputation for new users. And due to the difficulty of the question, some posts could still be silent even after a bounty.

Should we encourage people to comment their current progress, or some other ways are suggested? Or can we add a "Working on it" button to tell us someone is solving the question?

Comment: How would you enforce honesty with such a button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keep in mind that Readers pay attention to your Questions on a voluntary basis, so there's no better mechanism beyond asking a good Question to promote attention.

I'd expect the person who posted the Question to continue working on it until a solution that satisfies them is found.  Posting problems that are difficult, without any idea of how to proceed, does invite frustration.  It is better to have some concrete outline of what steps could lead to a solution and ask for help with that "program" than to expect Readers to digest the problem for you.

Adding more buttons or nonsubstantive comment exchanges is unlikely to ameliorate that frustration.  However if one has sufficient privilege, one might create a chatroom to discuss possible approaches, or visit one of the [existing chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com) to solicit ideas.